# JQueryのautocompleteがTypeScriptで認識されません

Tags: jquery, typescript

TypeScript, Jqueryとも初心者です．

### 現象

以下のようなTypeScriptのコードを書き始めたのですが、`autocomplete`のところで、

> Property 'autocomplete' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.ts(2339)

のエラーになってしまい前に進めません．（なのでプログラムはほとんど書きかけの状態です⇒正しくはないでしょう）

```
    // Get element for suggest (auto complete)
    if((( $("#manual-header-search").length > 0 ) || ( $("#manual-home-search").length > 0 )) && !_searchControlByJs){
        $("input.keywords").each(function(index:number,ele:HTMLElement){
            $(ele).autocomplete({
                source:['']
            });
        });
    }
```

WEBをそれなりに探してみて

```
interface JQuery<HTMLElement>{
    autocomplete(config:{source:string[];}):void;
}
```

なんていうコードを入れてみても効果なしでした．

解決法がわかる方教授をお願いいたします．

### 環境

Windows 10 + VisualStudio Code

package.jsonは以下のような感じです．

```
{
  "name": "es-search-js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "search-es.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.14",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.20.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/es6-promise": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1"
  }
}
```

不足している情報がありましたらお知らせください．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

すみません．自己RESです．

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/es6-promise": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1"
  }
```

が間違っていたようです．`jquery-ui`をアンインストールし

```
npm install @types/jqueryui
```

でやり直したところ、エラーは消えて

> (method) JQuery.autocomplete(options: JQueryUI.AutocompleteOptions): JQuery (+11 overloads)

とちゃんとannotationが出るようになりました．

失礼いたしました．

以上